# What is the difference between vertex and current in Feynman diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

As the title suggested what is the difference between them?

For example, $u$ quark turning to $d$ quark via $W$ boson, and the vertex should be written as

$$\bar{u}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma^5)d$$, well this vertex could be wrong, I haven't checked yet and just written it out of my memory. But anyway, why it is sometimes called current, which confuses me.
If vertex and currents are different then clear my doubts and confusion.

Comment: What is this you are writting?? Could you please help us understand the context? Is it the Feynman amplitude corresponding to some physical reaction? Please clarifiy.

Comment: What you have written is the weak charged current which  yields the Wqqbar vertex when coupled to the weak current $W^+_\mu$. Clear?